# The product of multiple univariate Gaussians

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, products

What is the final result of $$I=\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_1,v_1)\,\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_2,v_2)\ldots\,\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_n,v_n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\,v_1} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2v_1} } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\,v_2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2v_2} }\cdots \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2\pi\,v_n} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu_n)^2}{2v_n} }$$ in which $\mu_{1,\ldots,n}$ are mean and $v_{1,\ldots,n}$ are variance?

From the identity of two Gaussians multipliation, that is $$\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_1,v_1)\,\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_2,v_2)=\mathcal{N}_{\mu_1}(\mu_2,v_1+v_2)\,\mathcal{N}_{x}\left(\frac{\mu_1\,v_2+\mu_2\,v_1}{v_1+v_2},\frac{v_1\,v_2}{v_1+v_2}\right)$$ the $I$ can be computed one by one, but it is a daunting task. Is there a compact expression of the $I$?

Comment: Are these rv's independent? Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Comment: @zoli: Thanks for your response. What I want is simplifying the $I=\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_1,v_1)\,\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_2,v_2)\ldots\,\mathcal{N}_{x}(\mu_n,v_n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\,v_1} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2v_1} } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\,v_2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2v_2} }\ldots \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2\pi\,v_n} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu_n)^2}{2v_n} }$. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This might be interesting : http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf

Comment: @user22986: The previous comment of jibounet is definitive.

Comment: @jibounet: Thanks very much. That document provides the answer to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The product of Gaussians $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ simplifies to $S\, \mathcal N (\mu,\sigma)$, where
$$
\sigma = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{-2} \right)^{-1/2}
$$
$$
\mu = \sigma^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{-2}\mu_i
$$
and 
$$
S =  (2\pi)^{(1-n)/2} \frac{\sigma}{\prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i}\exp\left(\frac12 \sigma^{-2}\mu^2 - \frac12\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{-2}\mu_i^2 \right)
$$
The derivation is given in the report [Products and Convolutions of Gaussian Probability Density Functions](http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf) by P.A. Bromiley, which was pointed out by [jibounet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246358/the-product-of-multiple-univariate-gaussians#comment2533688_1246358).